# Gatekeeper Path Randomization

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-gatekeeper

I have an app that needs to write a symlink for a helper tool to `/usr/local/bin/gf`. The problem is GPR gets in the way and randomizes my bundle path, so instead of creating the symlink to `../MyApp.app/SharedResources/bin/gf` it links to some random path for the temporary disk image macOS mounts.

How do I detect that I am running in a randomized environment?

I tried checking the `com.apple.quarantine` flag, but not even that flag is removed when I move the app to `/Applications`.

Comment: Why don’t you sign your disk image and avoid GPR altogether?

Comment: Because ZIP is more convenient

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is for you to use a signed disk image.

However, if you do not like this approach, then there is [Patrick's suggestion](https://www.synack.com/blog/untranslocating-apps/) of untranslocating an app using a private API of the Security Framework:

```
SecTranslocateIsTranslocatedURL
```

However, this is likely to be patched up by Apple, which will break your app.